# Conditional loading in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React Component

```
const VideoElement = React.createClass({

    render() {
        return (
            <video autoPlay loop muted className="video">
                <source src={this.props.source} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        )
    }
});
```

And I want to have this output just if `window.innerWidth <= 640`.

My approach was to add an initial state like:

```
getInitialState() {
     return { isMobile: window.innerWidth <= 640 }
}
```

And add a a condition in the render() method but if I'm trying to access `this.state.isMobile` trows me an error with:

> window is undefined

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

It's my approach ok?

Comment: Can you try to access `window` from `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Are you trying to do serverside rendering?

Comment: You could rather check if the web isMobile inside your render method and return null when you don't want to show the `VideoElement`. The getInitialState is only called when the component is rendered first. The IsMobile flag can then be a prop given from a parent component. If you do it like this, I guess you can also use the `shouldComponentUpdate` method to check if the `nextProps.isMobile` differs from your currentProps

Comment: @HenrikAndersson Yes, I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing server side rendering of your React components, you need to do your `window` check from within the [life cycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) `componentDidMount`, which is only invoked once and only on the client.

When checking things like `isMobile` on the server side you should try to access what agent string the request came from and pass that information down to your client. Relying on window width in order to hide/show content should be done with CSS instead.

Comment: If I use componentDidMount() then can replace the output of the render()?

Comment: You can set a new state if you want to that `render` reacts to.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to do it, but if that's the case i would do something like this:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.mobile = false;
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.mobile = window.innerWidth <= 640
    }

    render() {
        if (this.mobile){
            return (
                <div>Hello Mobile</div>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>Hello Desktop</div>
            );
        }
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the operator ternary

```
return true ? ():()
```

for example:

```
render() {
    return this.mobile ? (
    <di> loading </div>
    ):(
    <di> content custom </div>
    )
```